# Use 'case' pattern matching to directly return result

Tags: swift, enums, switch-statement, pattern-matching

This is my code:

```
enum ServerResponse {
    case ok, error(Error), rawError(String), resend

    func isOk(response: ServerResponse) -> Bool {
        case ServerResponse.ok = response
    }
}
```

It doesn't compile with the following error:

> 'case' label can only appear inside a 'switch' statement

That's strange, since this is allowed:

```
func isOk(response: ServerResponse) -> Bool {
    if case ServerResponse.ok = response {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

But as we can see, it costs my extra lines of codes. I expect it to work since in Swift, only booleans are allowed. [The docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html) say:

> The value of any condition in an if statement **must be of type Bool** or
>   a type bridged to Bool

This means that this line should evaluate to a boolean, since above code compiles and the line of code is the condition inside an if statement:

```
case ServerResponse.ok = response
```

Why can't I use it to directly return a boolean inside a method (first code in the question)? Is there any oneliner that checks if a given enum property is a given enum case?

Comment: Two liner: `func isOk(response: ServerResponse) -> Bool {
        guard case .ok = response else { return false }
        return true
    }`

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to make your `enum` conform to `Equatable`, then you don't even need the case, you can simply use the `==` to check if your `enum` variable is of a concrete case.

```
enum ServerResponse {
    case ok, error(Error), rawError(String), resend

    func isOk(response: ServerResponse) -> Bool {
        return response == .ok
    }
}

extension ServerResponse: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: ServerResponse, rhs: ServerResponse) -> Bool {
        switch (lhs, rhs) {
        case ( .ok, .ok):
            return true
        case (.resend, .resend):
            return true
        case (.rawError(let string), .rawError(let otherString)):
            return string == otherString
        case (.error(_), .error(_)):
            return true
        default:
            return false
        }
    }   
}
```

Unrelated to your question, but defining `isOk` as an instance method and making it accept an input argument doesn't make sense. Either don't pass in `response` and simply use `self == .ok` or make the function a type method and then pass in the value.

Instance method:

```
func isOk() -> Bool {
    return self == .ok
}
```

Then call it like: `ServerResponse.ok.isOk()`

Type method:

```
static func isOk(response: ServerResponse) -> Bool {
    return response == .ok
}
```

Then call it like: `ServerResponse.isOk(response: .resend)`